# SQL Query to output to XML

Tags: xml, oracle, powershell, plsql

As part of a larger project trying to pull this data into Powershell, I am using a PL/SQL script to pull the undo values - current and recommended, from Oracle and output to an XML file that I can then parse with Powershell.  I would also eventually like the recommended undo parameter to return with a timestamp that the query was run at to compare how it changes over a period of time.

At this point though, I am just working with trying to output as follows:

```
<currundo>903</currundo>
<recundo>14400</recundo>
```

When I run this pl/sql I am getting:

```
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

Here is the code:

```
set heading off

DECLARE
    l_xmltype XMLTYPE;

BEGIN
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('SELECT SUBSTR(e.value,1,25) "curundo", ROUND(d.undo_size / (to_number(f.value) * g.undo_block_per_sec)) "recundo"
  FROM (
       SELECT SUM(a.bytes) undo_size
          FROM v$datafile a,
               v$tablespace b,
               dba_tablespaces c
         WHERE c.contents = ''UNDO''
           AND c.status = ''ONLINE''
           AND b.name = c.tablespace_name
           AND a.ts# = b.ts#
       ) into d,
       v$parameter e,
       v$parameter f,
       (
       SELECT MAX(undoblks/((end_time-begin_time)*3600*24))
              undo_block_per_sec
         FROM v$undostat
       ) into g
WHERE e.name = ''undo_retention''
  AND f.name = ''db_block_size''') from dual;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your "into" references and datatypes to yield this

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      l_xmltype clob;
  3
  4  BEGIN
  5  select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('SELECT SUBSTR(e.value,1,25) "curundo",
  6        ROUND(d.undo_size / (to_number(f.value) * g.undo_block_per_sec)) "recundo"
  7    FROM (
  8         SELECT SUM(a.bytes) undo_size
  9            FROM v$datafile a,
 10                 v$tablespace b,
 11                 dba_tablespaces c
 12           WHERE c.contents = ''UNDO''
 13             AND c.status = ''ONLINE''
 14             AND b.name = c.tablespace_name
 15             AND a.ts# = b.ts#
 16         )  d,
 17         v$parameter e,
 18         v$parameter f,
 19         (
 20         SELECT MAX(undoblks/((end_time-begin_time)*3600*24))
 21                undo_block_per_sec
 22           FROM v$undostat
 23         )  g
 24  WHERE e.name = ''undo_retention''
 25    AND f.name = ''db_block_size''')
 26    into l_xmltype from dual;
 27
 28  END;
 29  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Of course that simply put the output into a variable.  If you want it on screen, you can just do the select without PLSQL, eg

```
SQL> spool myfile.out
SQL> select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('SELECT SUBSTR(e.value,1,25) "curundo",
  2    ROUND(d.undo_size / (to_number(f.value) * g.undo_block_per_sec)) "recundo"
  3    FROM (
  4         SELECT SUM(a.bytes) undo_size
  5            FROM v$datafile a,
  6                 v$tablespace b,
  7                 dba_tablespaces c
  8           WHERE c.contents = ''UNDO''
  9             AND c.status = ''ONLINE''
 10             AND b.name = c.tablespace_name
 11             AND a.ts# = b.ts#
 12         )  d,
 13         v$parameter e,
 14         v$parameter f,
 15         (
 16         SELECT MAX(undoblks/((end_time-begin_time)*3600*24))
 17                undo_block_per_sec
 18           FROM v$undostat
 19         )  g
 20  WHERE e.name = ''undo_retention''
 21    AND f.name = ''db_block_size''')
 22    from dual;

DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('SELECTSUBSTR(E.VALUE,1,25)"CURUNDO",ROUND(D.UNDO_SIZE/(TO_NU
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <curundo>900</curundo>
  <recundo>41668</recundo>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I see now how that is working.  I appreciate your assistance!